# how to display pdf from localhost

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

In my application i need to display pdf files.

I tried to display in webview using google docs. My problem is pdf files are stored in localhost. when give this localhost url its not working. But other all urls are works fine. I checked my localhost url in browser its work fine. I can't able to see in my application.

It shows like this

" **Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source.Verify that document  still exits. you can also try to download the original document by clicking here** "

My code

> ```
>      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                 public void run() {
>             WebView mWebView=new WebView(PdfFiles.this);
>             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>             mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
>             String PdfUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/moodle/practice/document/"+Pdfname;
>             mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+PdfUrl);
>             //"http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf"
>             //mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+"http://www.ztsinc.com/MBT1_OI.pdf");
>             //mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+"http://www.ourwebsite/path"+lvForDialog.getItemAtPosition(position));
>             setContentView(mWebView);
>                 }
>             });
> ```

Comment: 10.x.y.z addresses are non-routable i.e. local network addresses. Google Docs GView only works with documents that are accessible online.